# Loading splash page while HTML styles and scripts get rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have all my JavaScript files linked on the bottom of my page. This way, the HTML can get rendered before loading any of the scripts. The only problem is that the HTML shows to the user before the scripts finish "decorating" the HTML elements. Is there an elegant way to show the user a splash page to your app before the scripts and styles kick in?

Comment: If your scripts only "decorate" your HTML elements, maybe you can do it with CSS instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `div` with `position: fixed` and a high `z-index` covering the whole screen as first element in body. A loading animation or text can be shown inside.

The very last line of the body then is a JavaScript which sets `display: none` to that `div`.

Comment: This is indeed the correct way to go. I think you made a mistake though. I would go for `position: fixed` and there is no such thing as `display: hidden`. It is eather `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`. The latter is the one that should be used here.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you can write you splash page and overwrite this with real content (which is hidden by default) by using javascript once it is loaded.

However there is a **huge** drawback to this solution: what if somebody has JS disabled?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FDcNx/